# jQuery focus function returns false

Tags: jquery, focus

I need some help with the jQuery focus function.
I have an input field and I would like to do something when Enter is pressed and the input field has focus.

HTML:

```
<form class="myform">
<ul>
<input class="inputfield" type="text">
</ul>
</form>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && $(':input').is(':focus')) {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

the .is(':focus') returns always false.

Does anyone know whats the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like it works http://jsfiddle.net/VVQ8x/

Comment: Not sure what your exact need is, but it is simpler to work with the form's `submit` event, rather than taking this round-about approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you assign the keyup event directly to the input fields?

```
$('.inputfield').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // Enter key pressed ... do stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of binding a handler to the textbox itself

```
$('.inputfield').on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

If you have jQuery ui you can use

```
$.ui.keycode.ENTER
```

if you'd prefer

Answer (score 0):

`.is(':focus')` should work for jquery 1.6+.

Or you could try wrapping 'old' javascript activeElement property in a jquery object and embedded it in onlaod js callback function as it:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13 && $(document.activeElement).is('.inputfield')) {
           //do stuff here
       }
    });
};
```

Comment: I like this solution and its working for me. But there is something strange: When I load the page I have to wait for like 10seconds before the key event is triggered...

Comment: not sure why but I changed action="" to action="javascript:void(0);" and its working fine now

Comment: Ive you tried by embedded your function in load callback. Ill updated my answer, stay tuned...

Comment: Ah, sorry... I commented under the wrong answer. Iam using the answer from Matei Mihai. But all answers are working... The one from Matei Mihai is the most elegant I think.